# Como capturar el id de un input html con JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente:

tengo un input:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="5" name="">
<input type="button"  onclick="x();">
```

Quiero capturar el valor del id de ese input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function x(){
    var id2 = $("#5").id();
    alert(id2);
}
</script>
```

Eso no funciona, espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Quieres que te retorne el valor del input, o el id del input(5)?

Comment: Para que queres obtener el ID si utilizas como selector el ID?

Comment: creo que hay que hacer la aclaración. No necesitas obtener el id porque en realidad lo estas indicando, lo que quieres es obtener el valor de la caja de texto que tiene el **id='5'**. ¿Verdad?

Comment: Viendo las demás preguntas que has realizado donde utilizas javascript y jquery, no entiendo como realizaste esta sin antes investigar en la red. (-_-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías hacerlo sin jQuery también, te dejo las 2 formas:

```js
document.getElementById('boton-js')
        .addEventListener('click', (e) => {
          var input = document.getElementById('5');
          console.log(input.id);
        });

$('#boton-jquery').click((e) => {
  var input = $('#5');
  console.log(input.attr('id'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="5">
<button id="boton-js">Probar</button>
<button id="boton-jquery">Probar (jQuery)</button>
```

Básicamente la forma de hacerlo en jQuery es a través de la función `attr` que sirva para extraer las propiedades, como el id, del elemento seleccionado.

Comment: Gracias amigo, justo lo que necesitaba

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta quedaria asi:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function x(){
    var id2 = $("#5").val();
    alert(id2);
}
</script>
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El método de jquery que te devuelve el ID de un elemento es attr(), o sea que el código de tu función debería verse así:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function x(){
          var id2 = $("#5").attr('id');
          alert(id2);
      }
 </script>
```

El método [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) devuelve el valor del atributo pasado como parámetro para el primer elemento que coincida con el selector especificado en la llamada al método.

Ejemplo:

```
<p id="parrafo">párrafo</p>

El ID del párrafo es: <div></div>

<script>
    var idParrafo = $( "p" ).attr( "id" );
    $( "div" ).text( idParrafo );
</script>
```